# What is this thin strake on the side of the Eurofighter Typhoon?

Tags: aircraft-design, eurofighter-typhoon

[image]

It looks like it's right where the canard would be if it was close-coupled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** I found a nice picture!

---

Strakes are used to "correct" and/or "channel" the airflow under specific conditions.

That one in particular on the Eurofighter looks like a strake producing a nice vortex at high AoA which rolls over the wing streamlining the airflow and helping in generating lift.

Indeed [this photo](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Spain-Air-Force/Eurofighter-EF-2000-Typhoon-S/3890939/L) nicely depicts and confirms that:

[image: Eurofighter condensation]

---

*Bonus material*

Strakes can also be see for example [on the F-18](https://www.bhmpics.com/view-mcdonnell_douglas_f_a_18_hornet_2-1440x900.html):

[image: F-18 strake]

In this particular case, they channel the airflow at high AoA in order to avoid that the turbolent airflow detaching from the trailing edge bumps into the the vertical stabiliser giving some buffeting.